# css selector when focus is removed from input

Tags: html, css

I have an input element.

1. The element has Black border initially.
2. I'm applying blue border to it when the element is focused.

**Requirement**: Now when I remove the focus from it, I want the border to be red.

I tried with `input:not(focus)` but it's changing the initial state also.

[jsbin link](https://jsbin.com/pudecat/edit?html,css,output)

```css
input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
}

input:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" required>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement, this should work.
Add a class to your input element, and a onblur tag to it which would refer to a function in the javascript.
Thus the element would eventually look on the lines of this.

```
<input type="text" class="textField" onblur="focusToggle()" required>
```

In the script tag, write this function

```
function focusToggle()
  {document.querySelector(".textField").classList.add("outOfFocus");
  }
```

And in the css add a style definition for the new class

```
.outOfFocus{
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

So finally, the whole thing would look something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" class="textField" onblur="focusToggle()" required>
  </div>
    <script>
    function focusToggle()
      {document.querySelector(".textField").classList.add("outOfFocus");
      }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the final CSS.

```
input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
}

input:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
.outOfFocus{
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

Hope this helped. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS [`:valid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) selector, this only works when you have the `required` attribute set and the `input` has a valid input though.

```css
input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
}

input:valid {
  border-color: red;
}

input:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" required>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a javascript event listener on blur so that when the user focuses out of the input the event fires... Then set the style of your border-bottom to the red color using `element.style.borderBottom = '2px solid red'`

See my snippit for an example...

```js
// define a variable for your element and target the first child using .children[0]
let target = document.querySelector('.field').children[0];

// now use that variable and add an event listener to fire on blur
target.addEventListener('blur', function(){

  // set your target elements border-bottom to the desired css
  target.style.borderBottom = '2px solid red';

})
```

```css
input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s ease-out;
}

input:focus {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="field">
    <input type="text" required>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```